# Why did my Gmail Notifications stop?

Tags: notifications, gmail, push-notifications

Recently I seem to have stopped getting notification when I receive new emails on Gmail. I used to get these until a few weeks back.

I have a Nexus 4 with the Android 4.2.2 and I am running the latest version of the Gmail app.

I have checked and notifications are turned on for the Gmail app in Settings->Apps

Anyone know why these might have stopped?

Answer (score 2):

This often happens if you have sync turned off or your refresh interval is not often enough. I am able to turn my sync on an off through a toggle in my notification bar, and most phones can do the same. Make sure sync for all services is on through that method.

It is also not enough just to have notifications turned on through the app settings. Make sure that notifications are also turned on in Gmail by going to Gmail>Settings>(your account) and checking the notifications box. You can also check the "Sync Gmail" box.

This works for me and I get my Gmail notifications pushed to my phone almost immediately.

Comment: "almost automatically"? You mean you have to do a little work each time? Or do you mean "almost immediately"? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

1. Do you have proper Network/Data reception (Not in Airplane mode, properly connected to WiFi, etc..)
2. Are you using Check Settings->Data Usage->'Set mobile data limit'?
3. In Settings, make sure 'Google' is setup under Accounts.

   - Select Google and then click on the email address that you're verifying. The 'Sync' submenu will come up. Verify that 'Gmail' is checked (it will also tell you the last time it sync'ed).